# connect Jasperreports community edition to another database server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Version - 6.0.1 (jasperreports-server-cp-6.0.1)[image]
Is it possible to connect jasperreports community edition installed on a ubuntu server to another postgreSQL database server?. I have followed this

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/connecting-jasperreports-server-yo....

When I try to create a data source (JDBC) , its showing nothing like in thedocument. It simply returns the blue menu (Library, view, manage)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to report on a different database you have to create a new datasource. Select view->repository, right-click in the tree somewhere and create a new datasource. You have to have the correct driver available but it will already have the driver for postgres. Put in the connection details and save the data source.

When you upload a report to the server, you'll have to then associate the report with the datasource (edit the report properties). This is all covered in the documents you get with the install e.g. JasperReports-Server-User-Guide, JasperReports-Server-Admin-Guide

Comment: I have referred  JasperReports-Server-User-Guide, JasperReports-Server-Admin-Guide. Added postgres driver and the application restarted. The issue issue is that when I try to create data source (explained in a variety of a documents) its simply showing nothing. It shows a blue menu with Library, view, manage as shown in the image attached to question.

Comment: What happens if you select view?

Comment: When I select view there are four options. Search Results, Repository, Messages and UI samples. While selecting repository -> Data Source -> Add Resource -> Data Source, its showing the blue window as shown in the question. The same window appears while trying to create Data Source from any other folder as well.

Comment: Assuming that you are logged in as jasperadmin or superuser or an admin user I think there is a problem with your install. You should check the jasper server log after trying to add the datasource and see if anything is happening there